# Xpath: Accessing Nested @alt Variable

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to build a Python Scrapy spider for TripAdvisor and am attempting to pull the bubble/star ratings for each review. I've gone through several online tutorials but they appear to be outdated as the tags for the bubble images appear to have changed.

Currently, I'm trying to pull the @alt variable text for each bubble rating based off the HTML from TripAdvisor. Here is the snippet I want to access:

```
<div class="rating reviewItemInline">
    <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_50">
     ::before
     ::after
    </span>
```

The @alt variable is located within the "ui_bubble_rating" class even though it doesn't appear in the object inspector for some reason. I can access it via xpath in Python using:

```
response.xpath("//span[@class[contains(.,'ui_bubble_rating')]]/@alt")
```

However, I only want to pull @alt from actual reviews on the page (there are several other bubble ratings for other hotels linked on the same page sharing the "ui_bubble_rating" tag). So I try to narrow it down by selecting only the span class "ui_bubble_rating" within a certain div:

```
response.xpath("//div[@class[contains(., 'reviewItemInline')]]//span[@class[contains(.,'ui_bubble_rating')]]")
```

This works to narrow it down to the 5 reviews per page I want, but as soon as I tack on the '/@alt' to the end of the above xpath, I get a blank list returned:

```
In [444]: response.xpath("//div[@class[contains(., 'reviewItemInline')]]//span[@class[contains(.,'ui_bubble_rating')]]/@alt")
Out[444]: []
```

If I just remove the first half of my xpath:

```
//div[@class[contains(., 'reviewItemInline')]]
```

and leave it like this:

```
response.xpath("//span[@class[contains(.,'ui_bubble_rating')]]/@alt").extract()
```

I get what I need: a list of ratings (i.e. ['4.5 of 5 bubbles,5 of 5 bubbles'])

I suspect it has something to do with how I'm access relative paths via "//" or "/" or any combination of "/*/", etc. but it may have something to do with the "::before/::after" lines as well as I'm unsure how these function. I'm just not versed in xpath to figure out why I can't extract this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the actual element you want to extract there is no alt attribute:

```
<div class="rating reviewItemInline">
  <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_40"></span>
</div>
```

So you need to get it by the class(bubble_XX), something like this should get you the ratings:

```
ratings = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'reviewItemInline')]//span[contains(@class, 'ui_bubble_rating')]/@class").extract()
ratings = [r.split()[-1] for r in ratings]
```

And later down the line you could parse these class names to something more useful for you use case

Comment: I'm not sure you are totally correct saying that the `span class="ui_bubble_rating"` does not have a `@alt` variable. When I script `response.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'ui_bubble_rating')]/@alt").extract()` I receive what I need: a list of `['4.5 of 5 bubbles','5 of 5 bubbles',...]`. But I only want `span class="ui_bubble_rating"` if it is nested in `div class="rating reviewItemInline"`. As soon as I tack on `("//div[@class='rating reviewItemInline']` to the `//span...` xpath above, I get the empty list `[]`.

Comment: You receive these from the hotel ratings at the bottom. I might be mistaken, but I understood you only want the ratings from the users.

Comment: And to add, the list goes empty because, like I said in my answer(the code there is copied from tripadvisor) there is no @alt attribute in the span tag for the user reviews

Comment: It appears that you are correct @Henrique. For some reason all the other review bubbles on the page have associated @alt attributes, but the ones in the actual reviews do not. Strange. This method does work though and I'm able to strip off everything but the rating with an extra underscore in strip for `ratings = [r.split('_')[-1] for r in ratings`

Answer (score 0):

Tr with a selector in this format:

`//span[contains(@class, 'ui_bubble_rating')]/@alt`

this should solve your problem.

Alternatives:

xpath: `//div[contains(@class, 'rating')]//span[contains(@class, 'ui_bubble_rating')]/@alt`

css: `.rating span[class*=ui_bubble_rating]::attr(alt)`

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that these do not limit the output to only @alt variables in the div class="rating reviewItemInline." It seems to be ignoring that part and just returning all the span class="ui_bubble_rating" from the entire page rather than just the ones tied to actual user reviews.

Comment: Then you need more contraints, you need to unique identify a parent for the current user, you will not be able to solve it by using just these classes from `div` and `span`, you need to share the html snippet for all ratings.